# Bitnami/Express 4.16.4 - npm install

Tags: docker, npm, bitnami

I need to install other node.js modules on the bitnami docker container.
I would like to install body-parser module to the container.  I've started the container with sudo docker-compose up and it runs fine.  i tried to modify the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file to install the body-parser but i get EACCES permission denied, access '/app/node_modules' error.  Can you help?

TIA,

Thomas

**** UPDATE 4/23/2019 ***
This is the docker file.
I added body-parser line.

```
## Dockerfile for building production image
FROM bitnami/express:4.16.4-debian-9-r166
LABEL maintainer "John Smith <john.smith@acme.com>"

ENV DISABLE_WELCOME_MESSAGE=1

ENV NODE_ENV=production \
    PORT=3000

# Skip fetching dependencies and database migrations for production image
ENV SKIP_DB_WAIT=0 \
    SKIP_DB_MIGRATION=1 \
    SKIP_NPM_INSTALL=1 \
    SKIP_BOWER_INSTALL=1

COPY . /app
RUN sudo chown -R bitnami: /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save body-parser

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: 'bitnami/mongodb:latest'

  express:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    image: 'bitnami/express:4'
    command: npm start
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DATABASE_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/myapp

      - SKIP_DB_WAIT=0
      - SKIP_DB_MIGRATION=0
      - SKIP_NPM_INSTALL=0
      - SKIP_BOWER_INSTALL=0
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Comment: Include in your OP the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and how you are trying to install the new module.

Comment: Could you share how you modified the Dockerfile?

Comment: updated the original post with the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.